# Is it possible to customize Atom language recognition based on filename not extension?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I searched a lot, but all are talking about extension-based language recognition. I'm asking this because we are using a certain filename for some purposes, and the content of this file is written in some language, however this file has no extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt and Dmitry's answers are instructive, here's what I did:
First I read Atom's doc about [customizing-language-recognition](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition). Originally I thought this only applies to file extension, but actually it also applies to filename.

```
'*'
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      'source.python': [
        'my file's name'
      ]
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin [file-types](https://atom.io/packages/file-types) to map a filetype to a new language. You can do this based not only on file extension but also based on filename. Look at "RegExp Matchers" section.